# Got error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path' using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I cannot run automate script (using Robot Framework) and got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\site.py", line 539, in <module>
main()
File "c:\python27\lib\site.py", line 518, in main
known_paths = removeduppaths()
File "c:\python27\lib\site.py", line 110, in removeduppaths
dir, dircase = makepath(dir)
File "c:\python27\lib\site.py", line 80, in makepath
dir = os.path.join(*paths)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
```

I have no idea what happened. Because before, it can run normally. I have been searching online but to no avail. Can't figure out what is causing this message and how to solve it.

Comment: Have you by chance created a file named "os.py", or a directory "os" where you've put a python package?

Comment: I have already solve, it's because the os.py is broke, thank you very much for your suggestion.